# SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: macos, websphere-liberty

the project working fine on windows 7 , shows those Error when deploy the project on mac .

liberty server ,eclipse mars ,

**strong text**[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMapppingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.prepareSQLJCall(Ljava/lang/String;ILcom/ibm/db2/jcc/SQLJSection;Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/SQLJColumnMetaData;Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/SQLJColumnMetaData;ZZIIIILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/SQLJCallableStatement;" the class loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/AppClassLoader) of the current class, com/ibm/db2/jcc/am/Connection, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader) for interface com/ibm/db2/jcc/SQLJConnection have different Class objects for the type c/SQLJSection;Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/SQLJColumnMetaData;Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/SQLJColumnMetaData;ZZIIIILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/SQLJCallableStatement; used in the signature
    at

Comment: Please format your code properly to show error as code. Also, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the existence of Launcher$ExtClassLoader in the error message, it looks like you've put a copy of the JDBC driver into your Java Extension Class Loader path (usually JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext).  Because of that, the environment has visibility to classes from both that location and the application class loader, and that causes a duplicate visibility that leads to the LinkageError.

There are extremely rare cases that require the use of the Java Extension loader, but I don't believe JDBC drivers are typically among them, so simply removing it from jre/lib/ext is probably the most straightforward solution.